# Пишу функцию, которая будет читать файл построчно или содержимое '<textarea>'. Но проблема с кодировкой

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8

Пишу функцию, которая будет читать файл построчно, и эта же функция будет считывать содержимое `<textarea>` c помощью explode("\r\n"). Но вот незадача - в случае с файлом нужно менять кодировку, а с textarea - не нужно (там она и так UFT-8). Как правильно поступить?

```
$arrayOfStr = file('fileName.txt')
foreach($arrayOfStr as $key=>$str){
  //Не работает...      
  if(mb_detect_encoding($str, array("windows-1251", "UTF-8")) !== "UTF-8"){
    $arrayOfStr[$key] = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str, "windows-1251"), "UTF-8", $str));
}
```

Выдает:

```
������ �� ��

//А так, если вместо if() выше, работает...
    $arrayOfStr[$key] = trim(iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $str));
```

Я окончательно запутался как правильно пользоваться `mb_detect_encoding`...

А когда делаешь:

```
foreach($arrayOfStr as $key=>$str){
    echo mb_detect_encoding($str, array('windows-1251', 'UTF-8')) . '<br>';
}
```

Выдает:

```
UTF-8
Windows-1251
UTF-8
UTF-8
UTF-8
UTF-8
UTF-8
UTF-8
UTF-8
UTF-8
UTF-8
UTF-8
Windows-1251
UTF-8
UTF-8
```

Как правильно менять кодировку?

Comment: Попробуйте [mb-convert-encoding](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: @DNS, пробовал... Не получилось

Comment: При формировании HTML кодировка указана (`meta charset`)?

Comment: @DNS, да. Видите ли, в чем дело, я пытаюсь написать функцию, которая берет данные из файла (парсит его) и эта же функция будет использоваться при вставке текста в <textarea>. Смена кодировки работает лишь в одном месте: или при загрузке файлов, или при вставке в <textarea>.

Comment: Но и браузер должен понимать, в какой кодировке ему вещают... Добавьте в голову инфу про кодировку

Comment: meta стоит в обоих местах...

Comment: Когда читается файл, используется file, чтобы читать построчно, а когда вставляется из этого же файла в textarea, то используется explode("\r\n"). Получается, что ниже этих функций код одинаковый. Но в случае с file нужно менять кодировку, а с textarea - не нужно. А код должен быть один. Надо было сразу обрисовать в вопросе всю ситуацию...